# Count and Sum inside a select with multiple sums and counts

Tags: oracle

I'm using sub-query factoring and I have a query that returns invoice lines, and in the end I have this final sub-query:

I've already tried Partition but without success

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN PC <> 0 THEN 1 END)                                                         AS A_LINECOUNT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PC > 0 THEN NR ELSE 0 END)                                                    AS B_PRODUCTCOUNT,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ALLOW_PAY = 1 THEN 1 END)                                                   AS C_INVOICECOUNT,        --- ERROR
    SUM(CASE WHEN ALLOW_PAY = 1 THEN MISSING_VALUE ELSE 0 END)                                  AS D_INVOICETOTAL,        --- ERROR
    COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_NON_LIQUIDABLE_PRODUCT = 1  THEN 1 END)                                  AS E_CONDITIONCOUNT,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN IS_LIQUIDABLE_PRODUCT = 1 THEN 1 END)                                       AS F_CONDITIONCOUNT

FROM MAIN_Q
```

The calculation of C_INVOICECOUNT and D_INVOICETOTAL is not correct because their values are repeated within each line of the invoice. Please consider that um MAIN_Q i also have a document_id where i can group by.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understood correctly, maybe not, but this is too long for comment. If yes, `C_INVOICECOUNT` can be count as:

```
count(distinct case when allow_pay = 1 then document_id end)
```

But the problem is with `D_INVOICETOTAL`. You have repeated values for each invoice here and details which do not repeat. If so, add row numbering to your query:

```
select main_q.*, row_number() over (partition by document_id) rn from main_q
```

and then in problematic places use `rn = 1`:

```
select ...
       count(case when rn = 1 and allow_pay = 1 then 1 end),
       sum(case when rn = 1 and allow_pay = 1 then missing_value else 0 end)
       ...
  from (select main_q.*, row_number() over (partition by document_id) rn from main_q)
```

Only first rows for each invoice will be analysed. Of course you can add row_number in earlier step.